# C Building Error: "undefined reference to `__imp_isxdigit"

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-errors, mingw

I'm trying to build a code at [here](https://www.kpqc.or.kr/competition.html).

You can download a reference code of 'SOLMAE' at the bottom of the page, which I'm trying to build.

But there are some errors when I do `make`.

Here is a log.

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3   -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3   -c -o fips202.o fips202.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3   -c -o common.o common.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3   -c -o fpr.o fpr.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3   -c -o codec.o codec.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3   -c -o rng.o rng.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3   -c -o cpucycles.o cpucycles.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3   -c -o poly.o poly.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3   -c -o keygen.o keygen.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3   -c -o sign.o sign.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3   -c -o falcon_keygen.o falcon_keygen.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3   -c -o samplerZ.o samplerZ.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3   -c -o benchmarks.o benchmarks.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3   -c -o fft.o fft.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3   -c -o precomp.o precomp.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3   -c -o vrfy.o vrfy.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3   -c -o randombytes.o randombytes.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3   -c -o normaldist.o normaldist.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3   -c -o nist.o nist.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3   -c -o test_dist.o test_dist.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3   -c -o shake.o shake.c
gcc   main.o fips202.o common.o fpr.o codec.o rng.o cpucycles.o poly.o keygen.o sign.o falcon_keygen.o samplerZ.o benchmarks.o fft.o precomp.o vrfy.o randombytes.o normaldist.o nist.o test_dist.o shake.o KAT/generator/PQCgenKAT_sign.o KAT/generator/katrng.o  -lm -o main
/usr/bin/ld: KAT/generator/PQCgenKAT_sign.o:PQCgenKAT_sign:(.text.startup+0x36): undefined reference to `__main'
/usr/bin/ld: KAT/generator/PQCgenKAT_sign.o:PQCgenKAT_sign:(.text.startup+0x385): undefined reference to `__imp_isxdigit'
/usr/bin/ld: KAT/generator/PQCgenKAT_sign.o:PQCgenKAT_sign:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `__mingw_vsprintf'
/usr/bin/ld: KAT/generator/PQCgenKAT_sign.o:PQCgenKAT_sign:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `__mingw_vfprintf'
/usr/bin/ld: KAT/generator/PQCgenKAT_sign.o:PQCgenKAT_sign:(.text+0x89): undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
/usr/bin/ld: KAT/generator/PQCgenKAT_sign.o:PQCgenKAT_sign:(.text+0x97): undefined reference to `__mingw_vfprintf'
/usr/bin/ld: KAT/generator/PQCgenKAT_sign.o:PQCgenKAT_sign:(.text+0xd0): undefined reference to `__mingw_vfscanf'
/usr/bin/ld: KAT/generator/PQCgenKAT_sign.o:PQCgenKAT_sign:(.text+0x100): undefined reference to `__mingw_vfscanf'
/usr/bin/ld: KAT/generator/PQCgenKAT_sign.o:PQCgenKAT_sign:(.text+0x241): undefined reference to `__imp_isxdigit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: main] Error 1
```

I assume that the errors are caused by mingw version.

So I updated mingw to latest version but it doesn't work.

I use Ubuntu 20.04, gcc 9.4.0 and mingw 9.3-win32 20200320.

What causes this error? and what should I do?

Comment: It looks like some inconsistency between a compiler and a linker. If you have Ubuntu and gcc, what's the reason to mingle it with mingw?